# Component type?

Tags: identification

[image: top view pcb]

Help identifying this through hole component.

No identifying markings.

Exploded when water dripped on the PCB.

PCB E0287100E.

Assy E0286400 from a Jandy variable speed pool pump speed drive 2.0Hp FloPro. PCB indicates 94V

[image: through hole exploded unknown type]

[image: location or exploded unknown component]

Comment: Can you show a schematic of where it was connected in the circuit?

Comment: Through hole, pool pump, explodes sounds like an ICL. https://www.digikey.com/short/ptz29d  Hard to tell specs without more info.

Comment: I have requested a schematic from the mfg.  nothing so far.  unable to remove the board as it appears to be anchored in resin.  I am adding a top view of the board with errors where it connected, the part was on the underside at the bottom of the oblong hole.

Comment: You don't need to ask the manufacturer; trace out the board and draw one yourself. It doesn't need to be the whole board, just the bit near that component.

Comment: Oh, never mind about that. I missed that the board was potted in place, and presumably you don't want to take a hacksaw to it since you're probably trying to repair it.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to figure a way to say just that :)  apologies for being really new and lacking  knowledge. I'll edit as I find more from research.

Comment: 94V is not 94 volt, but rather flammability rating according to UL 94V, V for vertical.

Answer (score 5):

Not much to go by, but by the way it was mounted, how it reacted, and the looks of it it seems to be an inrush current limiter a.k.a., negative temperature coefficient (NTC) thermistor.

These are designed to run hot, they could be ~100°C during normal operation unless additional circuitry is placed to avoid it. A drop of water in something like that would put a lot of sudden mechanical and electrical stress.

The size and package of it would help you to narrow down the range of possibilities (the variety of this type of components is not very high, perhaps not even a hundred types). But you will still have a few possibilities, you might need to reverse-engineer the schematic and circuit function to figure out the exact one.